# How to get an area code based off of zip code or IP?

Tags: javascript, database, api, user-interface, geolocation

I'm currently looking into getting an area code based on the IP address, or the zip code. I've looked into several APIs without success.

I'm using javascript to ask a user for their phone number. To make things easier, I need to automatically fill the area code box with the given area code. I've gotten the zip code from the IP address, but can't find a reliable way to get the phone area code.

### EDIT #1

After some discussion, I thought I would clarify some things. Area codes aren't very exact, and cities often have multiple. If we can get something *close* then that would work too.

I'd like it to be as accurate as possible, but there will obviously be some margin of error. If we can get it to guess some people's area codes then that would be good.

Thanks,

Jacob

Comment: I doubt there is a 100% reliable way to do this.  Area code is not always a 1 to 1 match with zip code.

Comment: I agree, but my boss just wants it to be close.

Comment: Well, you could scrape the data out of something like this: http://www.bennetyee.org/ucsd-pages/area.html -- this is by state, and there are often many area codes per state, but you could grab the first one or something.  Here is another that accepts zip as a querystring parameter: http://www.getzips.com/cgi-bin/ziplook.exe?What=1&Zip=12345

Comment: What do you define as "close"? Many cities have three or more area codes and cell phones in particular will use any of them with no regard to geography. Once upon a time my brother, mother,  and I all got our cell numbers at the same time from the same company and all three of us have different area codes. And I've moved to a totally different state since, keeping my number.

Comment: Good question. There are many factors. The goal would be to find one area code for the city where the user is located. Preferably the most popular area code for that city, but at this point we can't be too exact.